# How do I get a list of WCF named pipes on a system?

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

WCF named pipes appear in SysInternals pipelist.exe with their random Guid, not with their actual WCF path name.

How could I get a list of the WCF named pipes created on a system by their actual WCF path name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520967/view-current-opened-netnamedpipe-channels maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You mean programmatically?
These links can help you:

[Is it possible to use WCF discovery to expose a WCF endpoint that is using named pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068743/is-it-possible-to-use-wcf-discovery-to-expose-a-wcf-endpoint-that-is-using-named)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/23/console-application-to-discover-effective-named-pipe-path-of-a-wcf-net-pipe-endpoint.aspx

If you want to use a tool, you can use Process Explorer:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Hope it helps.

Comment: Regarding Process Explorer, if I select a process and go to the File entry in the bottom pane, I see its name as a guid, not the WCF.  For example: \Device\NamedPipe\988c42f6-81ea-49b4-bc1b-1ea3b4aae9f9.  Is there any way to see the WCF name?

Comment: @Pep it's long ago but for the sake of future readers - take a look at the console application article linked. WCF has its own way of translating from the configured name to the actual name used for the pipe.